# POST method of httplib python gives an error "socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Tags: httplib

The following code throws an error "socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known".

```
import httplib, urllib
attrs = urllib.urlencode({"username":"admin", "password":"admin"})
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("https://x.x.x.x:8181")
conn.request("POST", "/login", attrs)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
```

I don't want to use urllib2 module.
Could anybody help me?...
How to save the state of that server?, so that next time i directly post the values for the uri.

Comment: can you manually resolve the address?

Comment: Yes, I can manually resolve the address. The above thing working fine with urllib2 module. But the need to use httplib.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not specifying the non-default port correctly:
http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection

Try this instead:

```
   conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("https://x.x.x.x",port=8181)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("x.x.x.x",port=8181)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error with httplib.HTTPConnection, I found changing the url from "http://x.x.x.x" to "x.x.x.x" worked for me.  Try removing the "http://" or "https://".

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("x.x.x.x:8181")
```